# Incrementing decimal up to certain decimal then using next whole number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to transform a decimal value and add .1 to it. My problem is that if this value would become a '.5' value, it instead needs to round up to the next whole number.

For example: If I have a value of '3.1' this would become '3.2'
If I have a value of '5.3' this would become '5.4'
If I have a value of '6.4' this would become '7.0'

I currently do this using a case statement so if the '.X' part is 4 it adds 0.6 else it adds 1, but is there a more efficient/better way of doing this?

Example of current code:

```
declare @Example Decimal (5,1) = '4.4'

select case when @Example like '%.4' then (@Example + '0.6')
else @Example + '0.1' end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to assign strings to the decimal? Seems like a lot of extra conversion for SQL to do

Comment: As you'll see from all the answers, there's no way to avoid doing a CASE statement.   You might get some slight performance improvement from the suggestions though.

Comment: Should it round up only when the fractional portion =0.4 or when >=0.4?

Comment: @n8wrl It is possible that the values passed through will be strings, I would only want to modify values following the decimal format.

Comment: @shawnt00 I only expect values up to .4, any others would be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a decimal, then you should work with functions made for decimals and don't convert to string whenever possible. Here's how to do it with modulus.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (nums DECIMAL(5,1))
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES  (3.1),(5.3),(6.4)

SELECT  nums,
        CASE 
            WHEN nums % 1 < .4 THEN nums + .1
            ELSE CEILING(nums)
        END AS new_num
FROM @Table
```

Results:

```
nums                                    new_num
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
3.1                                     3.2
5.3                                     5.4
6.4                                     7.0
```

Comment: I think the `<= .3` should really be `< 0.4`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter because the data type is DECIMAL(5,1) but I guess   it might be bettter to change it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming negative values aren't an issue:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample Decimal(5,1) );
insert into @Samples
  values ( 0.0 ), ( 1.2 ), ( 2.4 ), ( 3.5 ), ( 4.6 ), ( 42.0 ), ( -1.2 ), ( -2.4 );
select Sample, Sample + 0.6 - 0.5 * Sign( Abs( Sample % 1.0 - 0.4 ) ) as [Result]
  from @Samples;
```

Not saying that it's a good idea, but it gets the work done.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the integer part (left side) using floor(x) and the decimal part using (x % 1).  Then you can either add the two together (if the decimal part < .4) or add 1 to the integer part (if the decimal part >= .4):

```
select FLOOR(@Example) + (case when @Example % 1 >= .4 then 1 else @Example % 1 end)
```

Comment: The `0.5` should really be `0.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not sure all the answerers are handling fractional values the way you intended. My version treats 0.4 as the cutoff for rounding up. All values where the fractional component is between 0.4 and 0.9 are treated the same way.

Doing it without a `CASE` block is not impossible. I suspect this isn't the shortest expression either.

```
declare @t as table (d decimal(5, 1) not null);
insert into @t
values (2.0), (2.1), (2.2), (2.3), (2.4), (2.5), (2.6), (2.7), (2.8), (2.9);

select d, d + 0.1 + (round(-0.8 + d % 1, 0) + 1) * (0.9 - d % 1)
from @t;
```

I'm assuming the numbers are positive since you didn't specify behavior regarding negatives.

As for the other approach to rounding: this is algebraically equivalent to the other answer but the logic might be more obvious this way.

```
d + 0.1 + 0.5 * (1 - abs(sign(d % 1 - 0.4)))
```

Here's another expression built on functions. Of course `coalesce` does expand to a `case` expression internally.

```
floor(d) + 0.1 + coalesce(nullif(d % 1, 0.4), 0.9)
```

The problem with your approach is in the implicit casts. And in those casts you're assuming that dot character is always the decimal mark.

EDIT:

If you're sure that the fractional portion of the input never exceeds 0.4 then I can think of another easy calculation.

```
d + 0.1 + floor(d % 1 * 2.5) * 0.5
```

These little tricks were more useful before SQL platforms had `case` expressions. I think it's not likely that these options really have any efficiency benefit.